# Chrome extension: Content script not picking up changes to chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build an extension to monitor the xhr portion of the devtools network tab.  With some help , I have been able to get the requests to be displayed on the service-worker console and I can log the Post requests. I'm also now saving the data "point" in chrome.storage. My next step is to read the data from chrome.storage.local, and have the content script log it to the console. However although I am getting no errors, I don't see any output in the console. No errors seen though. What am I doing wrong?

manifest.json:

```
{
 "manifest_version": 3,
 "version": "1.0",
 "name": "Hello World!",
   "description": "Learning how to make a chrome extension!",
 "icons": {
"16": "images/puppy16.png",
"48": "images/puppy48.png",
"128": "images/puppy128.png"
},
"action": {
"default_icon": "images/puppy.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"background": {
"service_worker": "background.js"
},
"host_permissions": ["*://*.cnn.com/"],
"permissions": ["webRequest", "activeTab","tabs"],
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["*://cnn.com/*"],
  "js": ["popup.js"]
  }
 ]
}
```

In my background.js:

(function () {

```
    var point;

    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function (details) {
     
            // Use this to decode the body of your post
            const postedString = decodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,
                new Uint8Array(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes)));
            console.log(postedString)
            const body = JSON.parse(postedString);
            point = body.CenterPoint.Point;
            console.log(point);
          chrome.storage.local.set({ 'key': point }, function () {
        console.log('Value is set to ' + point);
    });
        },
        { urls: [url] },
        ["requestBody"]

    );
    

})();
```

popup.js:

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function (changes, namespace) {
    for (let [key, { oldValue, newValue }] of Object.entries(changes)) {
    console.log(
        `Storage key "${key}" in namespace "${namespace}" changed.`,
        `Old value was "${oldValue}", new value is "${newValue}".`
    );
    }
});
```

Comment: You didn't show the content script. The popup script you've shown runs in the popup, which is a separate window with its own console: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu to see it. Also note that the popup runs only when it's shown, so it won't print anything for changes that occurred before it ran.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I messed up the manifest file (fixed now). But I was under the impression that the popup was a version of the content script. Following your directions I was able to look in the console of the popup script and find the desired output - does the popup script need a permission?

Comment: Content scripts are only for web pages, they are side-loaded in an isolated context, it's their sole purpose. The popup is an extension page, it should load its own scripts normally. I don't understand which permissions you meant though.

Comment: @user1592380 the popup script doesn't need a permission

Comment: @user1592380 Where do you get url in background.js?

Comment: Thank you guys - I took the URL out with a lot of other lines for brevity